# How to fix java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment not attached to a context

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmenttransaction

My application has a ViewPager with a bunch of fragments, when a button is clicked in Fragment1, actions are performed and a TransitionFragment appears, when a button is clicked in a TransitionFragment, the ViewPager transitions to Fragment3, this is how I implemented it:
MainActivity.class

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var mAdView: AdView? = null

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView)
        mAdView!!.loadAd(adRequest)

        initTab()

    }

    fun initTab() {
        tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.image1)
        tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.image2)
        tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.image3)

        tab_layout.tabGravity = TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL

        val adapter = MyPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, tab_layout.tabCount)
        pager.adapter = adapter

        pager.offscreenPageLimit = 2

        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tab_layout))

        tab_layout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                pager.currentItem = tab.position
                if (tab.position == 0) {
                    tab_layout.getTabAt(0)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.image1_focus)
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame) != null) {
                            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                        }
                }
                if (tab.position == 1) {
                    tab_layout.getTabAt(1)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.image2_focus)
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame) != null) {
                            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                        }
                }
                if (tab.position == 2) {
                    tab_layout.getTabAt(2)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.image3_focus)
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame) != null) {
                            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                     }
                }
            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                if (tab.position == 0) tab_layout.getTabAt(0)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.image1)
                if (tab.position == 1) tab_layout.getTabAt(1)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.image2)
                if (tab.position == 2) tab_layout.getTabAt(2)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.image3)
            }

            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

            }
        })
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tab_layout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                app:adUnitId="@string/banner_key"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                style="@style/MyToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/adView"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_txt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/sf_pro_display_regular"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="206dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="7dp" />

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tab_layout"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#2196F3"
        app:tabIndicatorGravity="top"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment1.class

```
class Fragment1 : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false)

        return view
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
 
            optbutton.setOnClickListener {
        
        val transitionFragment: TransitionFragment = TransitionFragment().newInstance(2)!!
            val trans = fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
            trans.replace(R.id.frame, transitionFragment)
        trans.addToBackStack(null)
            trans.commit()
        }

    }
}
```

Fragment1 and TransitionFragment only have a button
TransitionFragment.class

```
class TransitionFragment() : Fragment() {

    private var index: Int = 0

    fun newInstance(index: Int): TransitionFragment? {
        val fragment = TransitionFragment()
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putInt("index", index)
        fragment.setArguments(args)
        return fragment
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.transition_fragment, container, false)
        val trans_btn: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.trans_btn)

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            index = getArguments()!!.getInt("index")
        }

        return view
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        trans_btn.setOnClickListener {
            val tabs: TabLayout = activity!!.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout)
            tabs.getTabAt(index)!!.select()

        }
    }

}
```

Everything works well, but in rare cases the metric receives a crash notification like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment e{2dc5257 (30032337-24f8-4d9a-9da9-9db92da88082)} not attached to a context.
    at androidx.fragment.app.d.q(Unknown Source)
    at androidx.fragment.app.d.u(Unknown Source)
    at androidx.fragment.app.d.a(Unknown Source)
    at {packageWithFragment}.e.aE(Unknown Source)
    at {packageWithFragment}.e.c(Unknown Source)
    at {packageWithFragment}.e$f.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.hookedonplay.decoviewlib.b.a.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.hookedonplay.decoviewlib.a.b$2.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.a.a.j.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.a.a.j.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.a.a.j$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6102)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:961)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:822)
```

I can't figure out where the error is and what is causing the crash. Please tell me what could be wrong and how to fix it correctly?!

Answer (score 0):

I had kind of similiar case: when I went back from a fragment, I got crashed and had the same error as yours.

I did a simple check and put `Log.i ("info", x)` after every few lines in the `fragment` code and also overrdie `onStop` and put `Log` inside it (increasing the x each time). Surprisingly I found out that **the fragment code keeps running after `onStop`**, and got crashed whan it comes to get a `view` like a `Textview` etc, because the `Fragment Context` is NULL now... (In my case it was because I have a calling to firebase database, pulling data and then write it to a view. It takes a while, and if I leave the fragment before this proccess ends, the view in null).

I've searched a lot but couldn't find any information or other questions about it... weird.

**My soulotion:** I made a boolean flag, initialize it with `true` at `onCreateView` and  assign `false` to it at `onStop`. Now, before I call any view at the code, I validate the flag isn't false. That solved my crashes.

I still will be glad to understand that life-cycle and why `Fragment` code keeps runing after `onStop`... I hope I helped you.

Comment: This is the standard and big headache in Android. Check in detail the [Fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle) to understand it. Either, it will continue creating problems (it's a really bad implementation of the pattern) but at least you will be able to manage.

Comment: Tnx @Sourcerer, I've read it before, but it is not very clear about this anoying behavior... and they don't let you any soulotions to deal with such cases... What would you do to handle it?

Comment: I know it's really annoying. I had the both (Activity and Fragment) life-cycles printed in A3 and in front on me during a year. There is not (or I was not able to find) a simple solution. Only to trace every event and detect the situation. My case was medium complex (some background processes, some pull notification, some external activities) and took a long time to correct the most (still some crashes reported from Google Play).

Comment: Tnx... life is complicated